# Unable to Limit Retries Using Steeltoe with RabbitMQ in ASP.NET Core 6.0 Microservices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, steeltoe

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core microservices application where I'm utilizing the Steeltoe package to integrate RabbitMQ for messaging. I'm trying to implement a retry mechanism with a maximum number of attempts using the MaxAttempts property provided by the Steeltoe package, but I'm facing difficulties in achieving the desired behavior. Here's the relevant part of my appsettings.json configuration:

```
"Spring": {
  "RabbitMq": {
    "Addresses": "*",
    "Template": {
      "Retry": {
        "Enabled": true,
        "MaxAttempts": 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These are the steeltoe libraries that I am using:

```
using Steeltoe.Messaging.RabbitMQ.Attributes;
using Steeltoe.Messaging.RabbitMQ.Core;
```

I've also configured RabbitMQ services in my Program.cs as follows:

```
builder.Services.AddRabbitServices(true);
builder.Services.AddRabbitAdmin();
builder.Services.AddRabbitTemplate();
```

In my application, I have a RabbitMQ message listener method that processes messages. I want to restrict the number of retries for this listener using the MaxAttempts configuration, but despite setting the value to 3 in the configuration, the listener continues to retry indefinitely.

Here's a simplified version of my message listener method:

```
[RabbitListener(Constants.RECEIVE_AND_CONVERT_QUEUE)]
public void ListenForAMessage(ContentMessage msg)
{
    // Message processing
    // ...
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance or insights into how to properly limit the number of retries for the listener using the Steeltoe package's configuration. Am I missing something in my setup or code that's preventing the retry behavior from being restricted to the specified number of attempts?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration in appsettings.json is correct. It sounds like the RabbitOptions class may not be configured. To do that you can add this:

```
 services.ConfigureRabbitOptions(config);
```

If this doesn't help, could you try to make a minimal project and I can take a look.

Comment: I'm still unable to limit the retries of my RabbitMQ message listener. For better assistance, I've created a minimal example project on GitHub to showcase the problem. In this repository, you can find the simplified version of my application code. I'd greatly appreciate it if you could take a look at the project and provide insights on why the retry mechanism isn't working as expected.

GitHub Project: https://github.com/Bassam-Rahat/SteelToe-RabbitMq-Application

Thank you in advance for your help and expertise.